# False private key - why would it be false?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl

I'm opening my key file and it is saying that it is false and I have no idea why it that. My key looks ok when I open it with notepad. Why it's not working, I'm doing this for the first time so please excuse me if it's something obvious..

This is where I read it

```
// Reading private key
$fp = fopen("certs/cert.pem", "r");
$priv_key = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);
$pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key); // Empty
```

`openssl_error_string()` gives me `error:0906D06C:PEM routines:func(109):reason(108)`.

Comment: You have no error checking to see if you successfully opened and read anything from the file.

Comment: I did opened it successfully since I tried to print `$priv_key` out and it did.

Comment: Are the contents of the file a PEM-formatted private key?

Comment: Yes, it has `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`, then characters and at the end it has `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get a private key out of a certificate file; the private key isn't stored in the certificate, it's stored separately.  Where did you get the certificate from?  If you generated a CSR yourself and had it signed by a CA later, the key file was generated for you along with the CSR.  If you generated the CSR with openssl without specifying any further options, e.g.
    openssl -req -new
The key will be in a file named privkey.pem.  It will be delimited by ---- BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY --- and the contents are password protected (you were prompted for a password when you generated the CSR).

Comment: Yea, I did generate the key when I generated the public key. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How to diagnose OpenSSL errors:

Look at the error message:

```
error:0906D06C:PEM routines:func(109):reason(108)
```

Take the reason code (108) and determine the error:

```
grep 108 include/openssl/ssl.h
#define SSL_F_GET_SERVER_FINISHED                        108
#define SSL_R_BAD_DH_G_LENGTH                            108
#define SSL_R_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR                 1080
```

Now google for `SSL_R_BAD_DH_G_LENGTH`

Well not much luck. Looking into source tells that this error is triggered within

```
 ssl3_get_key_exchange() in s3_clnt.c
```

Probably this helps.